# Cross-Site Request Forgery Asp.net core .cshtml pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I ran code quality analysis tool fortify on my web application and it warns me "Cross-Site Request Forgery" on my edit and create cshtml pages.

I created asp.net core mvc web application by auto generating code via entity framework models. so the generated forms are working fine for crud operations.
I ran the application and found that there is a hidden token generated with default autogenerated code in html source. But why quality tools complaint about this security issue?

I tried the below but no luck. I used to add AntiforgeryToken in my razor mvc pages before. Not sure how to handle this scenario in asp.net core mvc. I thought it will be generate automatic token with out adding any specific code.

```
<form asp-action="Edit" class="myForm">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<-- my form elements -->
</form>
```

Comment: It is possible your tools are reporting a false positive.  It happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding method="post"

```
<form asp-action="Edit" class="myForm" method="post">
```

Comment: believe the default is false for anti-forgery when it comes to generating a token.  This case when the `method="get"`or is excluded its false and an action is not present. at least for aspnet core, so `method="post"` and `asp-antiforgery="true"` (tag helper) and then you will get a `__RequestVerificationToken` in the response headers  `<form asp-antiforgery="true" … ></form>`

Comment: so we need both method as post and asp-antiforgery="true" ? or just method =post is enough?

Comment: @Kurkula sorry, yes you can use both but its not required in later versions of .net core.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

The ASP .NET Core 2.2 generates automatically the antiforgery token in the HTML tag `<form/>` (eventually `@using (Html.BeginForm(..)`) only with specified POST method. Your form will be treated default as GET method therefore is not in your case generated antiforgery token. The ASP.NET Core apps don't generate antiforgery tokens for safe HTTP methods (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE). The fully explanation could be found in the article as mentioned before from @JamieD77: [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

There are some possible scenarios:

- **non-API scenarios:** The `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` is recommend. This ensures unsafe HTTP verbs (e.g. POST, DELETE, PUT and PATCH) actions are protected by default.
- **API-scenarios:**
  Here you could prevent also another actions (e.g. GET methods) with `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`.